# Best Practice: How does one organise assets in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a project that contains assets.

Some assets will need to end up in **Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData** (ProgramData folder).

Other assets are bundled with the EXE and should end up in the install directory.

During development I have both Debug and Release Environments (created by Visual Studio).

How can I organise my solution so that I do not have to replicate files all over the place?

This is how I see the final solution:

```
\Program Files\<my program>\Asset1.png

\ProgramData\<my program>\Asset2.png
```

In an ideal world Asset1.png and Asset2.png are setup in the Visual Studio solution so that they are not repeated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setting a file's `CopyToOutputDirectory` to true (in csproj) will result in it being in the bin directory regardless of whether you are in Debug or Release.

If you have multiple projects (csproj) in your solution (sln) with shared assets then you can eliminate file duplication (in your code repository) by adding a link to the file.  This is done when you click `Add=>ExistingItem`

[image]

Beyond this it's a software deployment issue where the answer depends vastly on what technology you are using to deploy it (e.g. WiX , MSI, Squirrel etc).

Do not worry about file duplication in the Debug/Release bin folders they are (re)produced every time you rebuild and should not be committed/considered part of your codebase at all.

Comment: I discovered that include the assets as resources and referencing them like that also help address my concerns

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a client side library manager

In Visual Studio, you have a new contextual menu item "Manage Client-Side Libraries…"

See [here](https://www.meziantou.net/library-manager-a-client-side-library-manager-in-visual-studio-2017.htm) for more information